# My options in BIOS are greyed out in MSI laptop

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, secure-boot

I've pretty entry level laptop -- MSI GF63-9RCX with i5-9300H and GTX 1050Ti

I've set the admin and user password both in BIOS settings several months ago and I don't change the settings much. Today I wanted to boot through pendrive but now when I opened the BIOS by pressing 'Del' it showed the password prompt which I typed correctly and after opening the BIOS I see that all the options (excluding some) are greyed out including 'reset to default' option too.

I want to do some changes in that please help me.

Comment: Do you have the ability to upgrade your bios? is it latest/stable/recommended version?

Comment: Did you go into the BIOS and then use the admin password to see if it unlocks those settings? Usually you have one password to get into the BIOS, then you have the separate admin account inside the BIOS that must also be unlocked to change some settings. Make sure your BIOS admin user is active.

Comment: I just got the update of firmware alongwith WIndows couple of months ago. And I think it's in its latest version.

Comment: I set both admin and user password the same. So, there shouldn't be any changes while logging with my password. But still I can't able to change the settings even the secure boot is on so can't change those too.